# Javascript problem with devexpress grid custom button

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, devexpress

```
        StringBuilder scriptFunction = new StringBuilder();
        scriptFunction.Append("<script language='javascript'>");
        scriptFunction.Append("alert('de')");
        scriptFunction.Append("</script>");
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", scriptFunction.ToString());
```

This is my code and it can run on page_load but i want it to run in my devexpress grid's CustomButtonCallback event. There is no error but it dont show an alert too. Do you have any idea?

KR,

Çağın

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CustomButtonClick="function(s, e) { var ID = e.buttonID }"
it returns button's id.

Answer (score 1):

RegisterStartupScript registers script to run after postback. DevExpress controls use callbacks to interact with server. So, no postback - no script running.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i want to use window.open function when i click custom button of devexpress grid. Do you have any idea about how can i do this?

Comment: Use client side custom button's click event. Add <ClientSideEvents /> tag to your grid markup right after <Columns></Columns> tag and set CustomButtonClick event handler there. For example: <ClientSideEvents CustomButtonClick="function(s, e) { alert('de'); }" />

Comment: yes you are right. i saw the same thing on another ask. And do you know how can i access my custombutton's text or ID?

Comment: Look into event args that are passed to the handler.